# ORA-00904 whlie executing impdp

Tags: oracle, database-administration, dblink, impdp, expdp

I'm trying to import `ORIG` schema into `TEST` schema.
`ORIG` schema was exported with filename `exp_orig.dmp`.

Following are the command I executed and its referencing parfile(`imp_testdb.par`).

command :
`impdp TEST/123@TESTDB parfile=imp_testdb.par`

imp_testdb.par :

```
remap_schema=ORIG:TEST
dumpfile=exp_orig.dmp
logfile=imp_test.log
directory=ORA_IMPROT
logtime=ALL
metrics=YES
exclude=DB_LINK
table_exists_action=REPLACE
```

When I execute the command, it crashes with following errors :

```
ORA-39068: invalid master table data in row with PROCESS_ORDER=-13
ORA-00904: "TAG": invalid identifier
```

I have no idea how to debug ORA-00904 and I couldn't find solution on google which applies to my situation, so I tried validating things one by one.

1. I created another user with the same spec and impdp to that user failed with same errors.
   => so it wasn't specific to target schema
2. I exported(expdp) the original schema again and impdp with the new file failed with same errors.
   => so it wasn't specific to a dumpfile
3. Then I started validating the parfile parameters
   => when I took out `exclude=DB_LINK` option in the parfile, impdp was successfully executed.

What reason could this possibly be due to?

Comment: Most likely you have either a DB Link named "TAG" or a reference to a remote object named "TAG" accessed through the DB Link. In some way there's a dependency on one or more database links in your schema.

Comment: @pmdba Actually, I don't have any database links in the exported schema. Could putting `exclude=DB_LINK` option when there's nothing to exclude be the problem?

Comment: Could be. In general there's no need to use `EXCLUDE` unless you know you have something in the schema you want to skip, so at a minimum your use of it is unnecessary. If there's potentially a bug here you might consider opening a service request with Oracle Support to see if it is known. It looks like there have been other such bugs when using `REMAP_SCHEMA` when the parent schema name is still referenced in PL/SQL code like triggers or function-based indexes.

Comment: @pmdba I copied the parfile from another parfile which I used to import schema with db_link. I didn't take it out because I thought it would't have any detrimental effect, but apparently it did.. haha. I'll make sure not to leave redundant options in the future. Thank you for your help.